# JQuery datepicker css formatting

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve Jquery date picker to look as in attached image. But what i ended up is the image attached (actual)[image: Actual]
[image: Expected]

1) First problem is how do i get that green and red boxes left aligned to those text boxes (part of text box), if i resize the window or with different resolution since it is being 2 different components it loses it alignment (as seen in attachment.

2) How to add a separator line between calendar icon and the text entry?

3) Add border to the text boxes same as seen in expected image box.

Code:
**HTML**

```
<span class="input-color">
 <div class="color-box-green"> </div>
</span>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="greenDate" [ngModel]="data.approvedDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'" class="datepickerIconIn" size="10" >
</div>

$(".datepickerIconIn").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
})
```

**CSS**

```
input.datepickerIconIn
{
  background-image : url('/assets/img/calender.png');  
  background-size: 20px; 
  background-Position : 98% center;
  background-Repeat :no-repeat;
  cursor:pointer;  
}
.input-color .color-box-green {
    width: 6px;   
    height: 20px;
    position: left;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: The issue is not in the posted code. see [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/bjmRGL).

Comment: @Louys there is a difference between what i have done and what is expected. I explained my issue in detail i guess. However thanks for checking

Comment: I don't get your last comment... In the CodePen I linked, there is no alignement issue. That's why I suppose it comes from somewhere else.

Comment: When i resize the window, color box and the date box displays in 2 lines.

Comment: I see. Then try with `white-space: nowrap;`. And, by the way, revise your markup: a `span` that contains a `div` is invalid. Look at this second [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/Zjqrbv).

Comment: @Louys.. thank you very much. Worked perfectly. Can you help me add a vertical line between calendar icon and the date text? Also because of the custom CSS, the text box border is gone, can i get that one too.

Comment: What a timing! I was editing an answer when I saw your last comment. The left input border is not an issue in my "clean" answer. ;)

Comment: Yup.. but even in the answer's code snippet, text box border is missing, it is only visible only on left and top.

Comment: I just updated the Codepen for an orange border... Which I see.... Even with a 3px border. This [codepen version #3](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/XByMJX) ;)

Comment: Woring perfect.. one last help a seperator bar between calendar icon and the text

Comment: The calendar icon is a background image... You could alter that image to add a bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments: *«When i resize the window, color box and the date box displays in 2 lines.»*

First, a `<div>` inside a `<span>` is invalid markup.

I suggest the following:

```css
input.datepickerIconIn{
  background-image : url('/assets/img/calender.png');  /* This obviously doesn't show here */
  background-size: 20px; 
  background-position : 98% center;
  background-repeat :no-repeat;
  cursor:pointer;  
}
.colored-input{
  margin:0 0 0 0.4em;  /* the left margin has to be the same has the .color left position offset. */
}
.input-color {
  position:absolute;
  top:0.5em;
  left:0.4em;  /* Left offset */
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 1.3em;
}
.input-color.green {
  background-color:green;
}
.input-color.red {
  background-color:red;
}
/* And so on with the colors */
```

```html
<div class="colored-input">
  <span class="input-color green"></span><input type="text" id="greenDate" [ngModel]="data.approvedDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'" class="datepickerIconIn" size="10" >
</div>
```

The same on [**codePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/XByMJX) where you can resize the viewport and where the datepicker is instanciated. You can notice that the color "marker" will stays the input on resize.

You just have to add an empty span, with the appropriate color class, in front of the input. The whole has to be inside `.colored-input`.
 *(Yes, I slightly renamed here... I strongly suggest you to use real meaningful class names for your elements. It help in the long run.)*

Answer (score 0):

this can be achive by css3 calc function.

.className{width:calc(100% - 5px);}